Unordered y-axis in multiline chart using dash
I am new to dash and struggling to create a multi line chart. I have a data and plotted it using dash and created a multiline chart. The reproducible code is given below-
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, callback, Output, Input

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': ['ab','ab','ab','ab', 'es','es','es','es', 'la','la','la','la', 'kl','kl','kl','kl', 'ys','ys','ys','ys'],
    'months': [1,3,6,12,1,3,6,12,1,3,6,12,1,3,6,12,1,3,6,12],
    'metric': [60.25,70.96,104.72,194.33,60.27,72.52,117.66,234.53,61.17,72.30,118.84,239.15,60.76,72.53,118.39,239.00,59.00,65.41,78.04,123.49]
})

app = Dash()

app.layout = (html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Metric assessment', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    html.Div(["Enter multiplier for metric    ", dcc.Input(
            id="some_number",
            type="number",
            placeholder=1, min = 1, max = 20, style={"margin-left": "15px"}
        ),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-content')
])
])
)

@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input("some_number", "value")
)
def update_graph(some_number):
    dff = df.copy(deep = True)
    if not some_number:
        some_number = 1
    
    dff['Total metric'] = dff['metric']*some_number
    dff['Total metric'] = dff['Total metric'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
    # dff = dff.sort_values(by = 'Total metric')
    fig = px.line(dff, x='months', y='Total metric', color = 'foo', markers=True, title = 'Metric vs months')
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

When I see the plot, the y axis values are unordered as shown below-

Even after sorting the dataframe on 'Total metric' column, the issue persists. What can I do to remove this issue and get the correct graph?

I cannot reproduce the issue.

In the callback, the 'Total metric' column is formatted (ie. as a string, not a number), so Plotly handles the corresponding data in the figure as categorical data instead of numerical.
Don't format the data, specify the yaxis tickformat instead (hover formatting will inherit the same format by default) :
@callback(
    Output('graph-content', 'figure'),
    Input("some_number", "value")
)
def update_graph(some_number):
    dff = df.copy(deep = True)
    if not some_number:
        some_number = 1
    
    dff['Total metric'] = dff['metric']*some_number

    fig = px.line(dff, x='months', y='Total metric', color = 'foo', markers=True, title = 'Metric vs months')

    fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=',.2f')

    return fig

